# JustCode logo How does it work?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to sharpen my skills by remaking some award winning websites.

With this one in particular
https://justcoded.com/

I don't get how the "JustCoded" text on logo on the top left is no where to be found to change. I spent an hour going through the css, js and html. Still don't see where it is.

Any help on how it's done would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You should include more context, like the part of the code around this logo and some CSS rules, possibly a few screenshots. If this site changes or goes down, this question will be useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the  ::before where the text, "JustCoded" is, you'll see that the class that affects it has a content: portion. The content replaces the inside of the a tag with the icomoon font item. Normally icomoon just consists of icons that act as fonts, but instead they made their whole logo be an icon, and are inserting the icon in that area.

```css
.header .logo:before{
  font: 48px/1 icomoon;
  content: '\e90a';
}
```

Comment: Ah i saw that, me having lower experience I mistook that to be just the ASCII code of the (&) like symbol.